# How do I remove links from a pdf?

Tags: pdf

I printed a web page into a pdf on my mac. How do I get rid of the links in it? I tried re-printing the pdf into another one to no avail.

Comment: I notice from your profile that you also have registered with askubuntu. There is an answer to your question on askubuntu [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106154/open-source-command-line-tools-to-remove-hyperlinks-in-pdfs).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a solution on a mac?

Comment: @DavidFaux: The answer linked to above uses pdftk, which is available for OS X, Windows etc. as well.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the top Google link to this question.  So here is a programmatic answer:

`ls *.pdf|xargs -n1 -I% pdfjam "%"`

This will take all pdf files in the current directory and process them through pdfjam (`sudo apt-get install pdfjam` if you don't have it.  On a mac, `brew install pdfjam`).  Pdfjam will output the same filename, with '-pdfjam' suffix prior to the `.pdf` extension.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on a Mac `10.13.6` and pdfjam `2.08.`

Comment: To install `pdfjam`, I ran `apt-get install texlive-extra-utils`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to get rid of it is to save file as a pdf one and edit it after. I once used PDFescape http://www.pdfescape.com/ it was pretty effective for me, although I used the most simple function - I needed to add some text and to erase another part. Also over here there is an instruction on [editing pdf](http://www.askwiki.net/How-to-Edit-a-Pdf) files, this might be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an easy way. If you use Open with `Microsoft word` (I am using 2013). When it asks for conversion confirmation press `"yes"`. Then edit and remove them. Browsing by page would be easier. After finishing editing `Export it to PDF`. make sure you set `Make Bookmark` option on to get pdf navigation menu (bookmark).

Answer (score 0):

Only for Mac Users: Open the document in preview, go to FILE -> Export. It then asks you where you want to save it and make sure the FOMRAT is PNG before you save it. This will get rid of all links.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was simply making the hyperlinks not clickable – not completely removing them and the following worked for me:

1. Opening the PDF in Chrome
2. Opening the Print dialogue – Cmd+P or File -> Print
3. Save as PDF

Produced the same document as the source one, just without the clickable hyperlinks.